# On gradient boosting and types of encodings

Tags: boosting, categorical-encoding

I am having a look at this [material](https://github.com/lesteve/euroscipy-2019-scikit-learn-tutorial/blob/master/notebooks/02_basic_preprocessing.ipynb) and I have found the following statement:

> For this class of models [Gradient Boosting Machine algorithms] [...] it is both safe and significantly
> more computationally efficient use an arbitrary integer encoding [also known as Numeric Encoding] for
> the categorical variable even if the ordering is arbitrary [instead of
> One-Hot encoding].

Do you know some references that support this statement? I get that Numeric Encoding is more computationally efficient than One-Hot Encoding, but I would like to know more about their supposed equivalence to encode unordered categorical variables in Gradient Boosting Methods.

Comment: I can think of some informal references against this statement but non formally supporting it.